# Is there a way to trigger Material-UI Modal close manually

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, integration-testing, react-testing-library

I use the Popover component, it is like [Modal](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/).

I have a test like this:

```
  test('should close popover when clicked two times', () => {
    userEvent.click(targetElem);
    let popover = screen.getByTestId('popover');
    document.body.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Escape', code: 'Escape' }));
  });
```

I want to close my Popover, but this code doesn't work correctly.
How can I test popover close case in jest, react-testing-library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have the following simple component with a button that triggers a `Modal` on click.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal'

const SimpleModal = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

    const handleOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true)
    }
    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={handleOpen}>
                Open Modal
            </button>
            <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
                <h1>Text in Modal</h1>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SimpleModal
```

You can simulate an `Escape` key event using `fireEvent.keyDown` on the modal itself once it's showing, which will close the modal.

```js
test('should close modal when "Escape" key is pressed', () => {
    render(<SimpleModal />);
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Open Modal'));
    expect(screen.getByText('Text in Modal')).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.keyDown(screen.getByText('Text in Modal'), {
      key: 'Escape',
      code: 'Escape'
    });
    expect(screen.queryByText('Text in Modal')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```